# Enabling prometheus in config file jhipster fails to start

Tags: jhipster

I am following this URL https://www.jhipster.tech/monitoring/ to enable monitoring in my JHipster(v6.2.0) application.

My config looks like this

````
  metrics:
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    logs: # Reports metrics in the logs
      enabled: false
      report-frequency: 60 # in seconds ```
````

When I start the application it fails to start with below error

```
Binding to target [Bindable@5e37ff61 type = io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(value=jhipster, prefix=jhipster, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false)]] failed:

    Property: jhipster.metrics.prometheus.enabled
    Value: true
    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml]:129:16
    Reason: The elements [jhipster.metrics.prometheus.enabled] were left unbound.

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Am i missing any jar or config?

Comment: What kind of application is your project? (monolithic, microservice, ...)

Comment: @vpq it is a microservice and I have enabled this is the gateway application

Comment: @GaëlMarziou No, i am not using the registry for config

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou What do you mean by disabling it?

Comment: You said you're not using registry for config, it's the default behavior, so unless you disabled it explicitly you still have it and your configuration is not the one you think?